# Big calendar populated from a database

Tags: coldfusion, calendar

I am using ColdFusion 9.1.2 and jQuery 1.6.2 and SQL Server 2008.

I am creating a web site that has a ton of dates in it. I want to spit out those dates into a full page calendar for the entire month and have users be able to scroll through each month.

I haven't heard of a ColdFusion events calendar feature.  I am not looking for the jQuery datepicker thing.

What is a free and easy calendar solution for ColdFusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the best luck with FullCalendar.  It is a jQuery plugin which you can find [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).  Also, Raymond Camden has blogged an example using it with ColdFusion which you can find [here](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2011/6/17/FullCalendar-jQuery-Plugin)

Comment: That's a nice calendar. And it would probably be easy to integrate into my web site, since I use so much jQuery anyway. The problem is I will have too many events on each day. I am going to make a flat calendar, with rows for each month and day.  Thanks!

Comment: I use it on a site that has lots of events, even on the same day, and while it doesn't look fantastic, the calendar does do a good job of adjusting the size to look the best it can.  Obviously, you need to do whats right for your site, but I thought I would mention that it does do a decent job of displaying lots of events.

Comment: Oh, and it also has the agenda display format which might do a little better.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for something similar yesterday - the best that I found was [John Mason's Event Calendar](http://eventcalendar.riaforge.org/) on riaforge. It's the mostly recently updated and somewhat modern looking one compared to Ben Nadel's or [any of the others on riaforge.](http://www.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.search#calendar)

If you end up developing your own, please please please open source it. There's a big need for a modern CF calendar.

Comment: I think I am just going to output an accordion with a row for each day. In my case, I want to be able to output 100 characters per event, so a little box might be too confining. And since it's just rows, it's easy peasy.  I'll send you a link when I am done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could give Ben Nadel's Kinky Calendar a try:

http://www.bennadel.com/projects/kinky-calendar.htm

Comment: From what I understand, his Kinky Calendar stops in the year 2012.